# How to add Mailchimp to existing signup box

Tags: mailchimp

I'm very new to Mailchimp. I would like to add mailchimp to existing PHP based signup form. I don't want to use the forms from Mailchimp. I've searched on Google but didn't find any solution yet. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you refer the following link?

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-add-my-signup-form-on-my-website/ . You would have come across if you had given proper search query.

Comment: The actual kb article that addresses the question is http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-host-my-own-sign-up-forms . The original respondent would have come across it if they had given the question a proper read. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a short tutorial to help anyone facing this issue. Please check it here: http://www.sunarlim.com/2014/04/mailchimp-sign-form-php-jquery-ajax/

MailChimp APIs are actually very easy to understand and they provide massive list of references and their own libraries to help developers to implement.